# Save Dialog when User Cancel

Tags: vb.net, save

I need to save a file from different locations in my application, so I created a sub for that; everything work just fine, except when a user clicks cancel when the save dialog shows up; if user clicks "Cancel", the form will close; I tried the TWO Options shown in the code below but both did not work; any suggestion will be appreciated:

```
   Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SaveFileDialog()
End Sub

Sub SaveFileDialog()
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Dim MekdamSaveFile = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(MekdamSaveFile, "")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(MekdamSaveFile, RichTextBox2.Text, True)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show("The File:  has been changed, do you want to save it? ", _
    "Mekdam Message 701", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        e.Cancel = True
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        'PROCEED...
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        SaveFileDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Open the form again? `Form1.Show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your SaveFileDialog Subroutine into a Function, then return False if anything other than OK was done, then test it in your FormClosing EventHandler and stop the Close.

**Modified SaveFileDialog**

```
Function SaveFileDialog() As Boolean
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Dim MekdamSaveFile = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(MekdamSaveFile, "")
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(MekdamSaveFile, RichTextBox2.Text, True)
        Return True 'Return True if Ok is clicked
    Else
        Return False 'return false this will give you something to conditionaly test
    End If
End Function
```

**Modified FormClosing EventHandler**

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim result = MessageBox.Show("The File:  has been changed, do you want to save it? ", _
"Mekdam Message 701", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        e.Cancel = True
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        'PROCEED...
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        If Not SaveFileDialog() Then e.Cancel = True 'this will abort the close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are the man Mark; I should visit you when I am in California next time :-)

Comment: Trying to catch me in the State could be interesting :), next week florida, then Wisconsin  ...  Glad I was able to be help.

Answer (score 0):

Is not too much clear what you need... try this:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Load

    Do Until Not ShowSaveFileDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel
        ShowSaveFileDialog()
    Loop

End Sub

Private Function ShowSaveFileDialog() As DialogResult

    Using SFD As New SaveFileDialog With
        {
         .Filter = "TXT Files (*.txt)|*.txt",
         .ValidateNames = True
        }

        AddHandler SFD.FileOk, AddressOf SFD_FileOk
        Return SFD.ShowDialog()
        RemoveHandler SFD.FileOk, AddressOf SFD_FileOk

    End Using

End Function

Private Sub SFD_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)

    IO.File.AppendAllText(sender.FileName, RichTextBox2.Text, System.Text.Encoding.Default)

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You are right ElektroStudios, my question was not clear, so I revised the code to show exactly the problem. If the used close form, it will show the save dialog, if user click CANCEL on the dialog, the form closes, I do not want it to close if user click CANCEL.